# Dropdown Menu shifts the content down

Tags: jquery, html, css, browser, drop-down-menu

I have this dropdown, and it is like this when it is not clicked over:

[image]

But when I click in order to select one option, it shifts the content below it (Movies) down:

[image]

I want this dropdown covers the content below, instead of pushing them down.

Here is my html code:

```
<div style="background-color: white; width: 100%; position:relative;">
  <div class="styled-select">
                <select id="campaignListId" name="campaignId" onmousedown="if(this.options.length>5){this.size=5;}" onchange='this.size=0;' onblur="this.size=0;">
                    <option value="1">First</option>
                    <option value="2">Second</option>
                    <option value="3">Third</option>
                    <option value="4">Fourth</option>
                    <option value="5">Fifth</option>
                    <option value="6">Sixth</option>
                    <option value="7">Seventh</option>
                    <option value="8">Eighth</option>
                    <option value="9">Ninth</option>
                    <option value="10">Tenth</option>
                </select>
  </div>
<div style="background-color: #F8F8F8; width: 100%; position:relative; left: 0px; ">
  <br />
    <div style="width: 944px; position:relative;  margin: 0 auto; ">
                    <font style="font-size: 22px; font-weight: bold; ">

                        <span id="spanMovies" style="cursor: pointer; color: #4F9DD0; text-decoration: underline; " >
                            Movies
                        </span>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I used this code:

> onmousedown="if(this.options.length>5){this.size=5;}"
>   in order to show only 5 items of my options.

This is my CSS:

```
.styled-select select {
            background: transparent;
            width: 944px;
            padding: 5px;
            font-size: 32px;
            font-weight: bold; 
            font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
            color: #4F9DD0;
            line-height: 1;
            border: 0;
            border-radius: 0;

            -webkit-appearance: none;
            -moz-appearance: none;

            -o-appearance: none;
        }
        .styled-select {
            overflow: hidden;
            background: url(resources/img/campaignSelector.png) no-repeat right #ddd;

            background-color: white;
            width: 944px; 
            position:relative;  
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
```

Comment: post full code. where is the Movies anchor tag?

Comment: `<font>` has been deprecated and should no longer be used.

Comment: @Banik I added those parts to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would have to position the `select` absolutely for that.

It will take the `select` our of the flow and stop it interacting with other elements.

```css
.styled-select {
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  height: 1.2em;
}
.styled-select select {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.movie {
  background: grey;
}
span {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #4F9DD0;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div class="styled-select">
  <select id="campaignListId" name="campaignId" onmousedown="if(this.options.length>5){this.size=5;}" onchange='this.size=0;' onblur="this.size=0;">
    <option value="1">First</option>
    <option value="2">Second</option>
    <option value="3">Third</option>
    <option value="4">Fourth</option>
    <option value="5">Fifth</option>
    <option value="6">Sixth</option>
    <option value="7">Seventh</option>
    <option value="8">Eighth</option>
    <option value="9">Ninth</option>
    <option value="10">Tenth</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="movie">

  <span id="spanMovies">Movies</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I added also my css to the question

Comment: OK...but it's not really required. The basic answer is to use `position:absolute` on the `select`....but you will need to give the parent div some height otherwise it will collapse.

Comment: I added position: absolute and height, but the problem is that now the dropdown goes under the grey background of movies. @Paulie_D

Comment: Just give it select a higher `z-index`...probably 2 or 3 (`z-index:2` for instance) and see what happens.

Comment: Sorry, I missed a <div> before I edited my code, and I think that div (the one with background-color:#F8F8F8) causes problem. If you add that one to your working code, you will see how it looks like.

Answer (score 1):

One way is add and remove class following way using javascript.

```
<select id="campaignListId" name="campaignId" onmousedown="if(this.options.length>5){this.size=5; this.parentNode.className='styled-select classname'}" onchange='this.size=0; this.parentNode.className="styled-select";' onblur="this.size=0; this.parentNode.className='styled-select';">

.classname{
   position:absolute;
 }
```

And remove `position:relative` from movies div

```css
.styled-select select {
            background: transparent;
            width: 944px;
            padding: 5px;
            font-size: 32px;
            font-weight: bold; 
            font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
            color: #4F9DD0;
            line-height: 1;
            border: 0;
            border-radius: 0;

            -webkit-appearance: none;
            -moz-appearance: none;

            -o-appearance: none;
        }
        .styled-select {
            overflow: hidden;
            background: url(resources/img/campaignSelector.png) no-repeat right #ddd;

            background-color: white;
            width: 944px; 
            position:relative;  
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
        
        .classname{
          position:absolute;
          
        }
```

```html
<div class="styled-select">
                <select id="campaignListId" name="campaignId" onmousedown="if(this.options.length>5){this.size=5; this.parentNode.className='styled-select classname'}" onchange='this.size=0; this.parentNode.className="styled-select";' onblur="this.size=0; this.parentNode.className='styled-select';">
                    <option value="1">First</option>
                    <option value="2">Second</option>
                    <option value="3">Third</option>
                    <option value="4">Fourth</option>
                    <option value="5">Fifth</option>
                    <option value="6">Sixth</option>
                    <option value="7">Seventh</option>
                    <option value="8">Eighth</option>
                    <option value="9">Ninth</option>
                    <option value="10">Tenth</option>
                </select>
  </div>
  <div style="width: 944px;  margin: 0 auto; ">
                    <font style="font-size: 22px; font-weight: bold; ">

                        <span id="spanMovies" style="cursor: pointer; color: #4F9DD0; text-decoration: underline; " >
                            Movies
                        </span>
</div>
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v2xu2801/)**

Comment: I tried your code but look what is the result with my code, actually there was a missing <div> in my original code that I added.

Comment: @reshad you have not removed `position:relative` as i said in answer. Check after it is removed. https://jsfiddle.net/v2xu2801/3/